# No replica set members match selector "Primary()" using Python(pymongo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

I am having a ServerSelectionTimeoutError No replica set members match selector "Primary()" when executing a connection to a mongodb database using pymongo. previously this connection string is functioning without any error. Not sure what happened and what should be added in the connection string to solve this error. I am using python v3.10

```
connection_string = "mongodb://username:" + urllib.parse.quote("password") + "@host:port/db_name"
client = MongoClient(connection_string)
mydb = client.get_database('db_name')


collection = mydb["collection_name"]
pipeline = [SAMPLE_PIPELINE]
cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```